# Bash group matching

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I am using bash 3.1.17(1)-release and script below. It doesn't show group match for input  i.e. 4fwk2_dev 2fwk5_dev

```
echo $FWK
FWK_REGEX="/(\d{1,3})fwk(\d)_dev/"
if [[ $FWK =~ $FW_REGEX ]]; then
   echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi
```

**Output**

```
4fwk2_dev 2fwk5_dev
```

I would expect it to match 4, and also 2 if I add `echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`. And if I add `g` (global) to regex then hope it would process both `4fwk2_dev` and `2fwk5_dev`.

Comment: bash regular expressions do not use pcre syntax. Lose the slashes, and use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` in place of `\d`

Comment: A note about bash regexes: the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) references [`regex(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) and that page references [`regex(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) and *there* you can read about POSIX extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
echo $FWK
FWK_REGEX="([0-9]{1,3})fwk([0-9])_dev"
if [[ $FWK =~ $FWK_REGEX ]]; then
   echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi
```

I've replaced the regex and corrected the typo in the variable name.

However, I have Bash 4.3.42(1), so YMMV.

Comment: Thnx a lot , works for first word in line, looking for 'global' like option in docs to process every word in line

Comment: `\d` for Digits is comes from `Perl` and isn't part of the POSIX style regex's that `bash` uses. `[0-9]` for digits is most concise. `[[:digit:]]` is the direct equivalent of `\d`, for letters, perl uses `\w` but bash uses: `[[:alpha:]]`. You can find them all in the grep manual. https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html